.NET RSACryptoServiceProvider throws "Access is denied." in GitLab hosted runner
I have some C# code (.NET Framework 4.7.2 - unfortunately can't be upgraded) that generates an RSA key pair using the BouncyCastle library, and then converts it to the .NET-native RSA:
var bouncyKeyGen = new RsaKeyPairGenerator();
bouncyKeyGen.Init(
  new RsaKeyGenerationParameters(
    new BigInteger("10001", 16),
    SecureRandom.GetInstance("SHA1PRNG"),
    1024,
    80
  )
);
var bouncyKeyPair = bouncyKeyGen.GenerateKeyPair();
var nativeKeyPair = DotNetUtilities.ToRSA(keys.Private as RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters);

However, when calling this last .ToRSA method from my unit tests (running on a GitLab hosted Windows runner) I get a CryptographicException:
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException : Access is denied.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils._CreateCSP(CspParameters param, Boolean randomKeyContainer, SafeProvHandle& hProv)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.CreateRSAProvider(RSAParameters rp)
   at MyCode.Method in C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\path\to\my\code.cs:line 120

It works fine when specifying an explicit CspParameter with Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore - but doing so would change the behavior for the sake of allowing the unit tests to run on GitLab's hosted Windows runner, something I am not interested in.
What is causing this "Access is denied" error, and how can I fix the environment to allow the RSA key to be converted?

Unfortunately following the stack trace leads to an internal call for the _CreateCSP method, which means I can't get more information on what the "Access is denied" error relates to.
From reading a variety of blog posts and Microsoft documentation, I have gathered that Windows persists RSA keys to a directory by default, and that the unhelpful "Access is denied" can be a result of the user not having access to those directories. I have tried testing access to all the directories mentioned in Microsoft's documentation, prior to running my script in the GitLab runner.
I have added the following to my .gitlab-ci.yml:
test:
  # ...
  before_script:
    - |
      # all the paths used for RSA key storage must exist - apparently that's not the case on the hosted runners
      # see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/key-storage-and-retrieval
      $UserSid = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().User.Value;
      $AppdataStoragePath = Join-Path $env:APPDATA 'Microsoft\Crypto\RSA';
      $ProfilesStoragePath = Join-Path $env:ProgramData 'Microsoft\Crypto\RSA';
      $KeyStoragePaths = $(
        (Join-Path $ProfilesStoragePath 'MachineKeys'),
        (Join-Path $ProfilesStoragePath 'S-1-5-18'),
        (Join-Path $ProfilesStoragePath 'S-1-5-19'),
        (Join-Path $ProfilesStoragePath 'S-1-5-20'),
        (Join-Path $AppdataStoragePath $UserSid),
        (Join-Path $env:APPDATA 'Microsoft\Crypto\Keys'),
        (Join-Path $env:ProgramData 'Microsoft\Crypto\SystemKeys')
      );
      foreach ($Dir in $KeyStoragePaths) {
        if (-not (Test-Path $Dir -ErrorAction Continue)) {
          Write-Host "Creating directory for key storage: $Dir";
          New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Dir -Force -ErrorAction Continue;
        } else {
          Write-Host "Directory for key storage already exists: $Dir";
        }
        $Rule =New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", "FullControl", "Allow")
        $Acl = Get-Acl $Dir
        $Acl.SetAccessRule($Rule)
        $Acl | Set-Acl -Path $Dir
        Write-Host "  Can access directory for key storage (Test-Path)? $(Test-Path $Dir)";
        Set-Content -Path (Join-Path $Dir 'test.txt') -Value 'Test' -Force -ErrorAction Continue;
        Write-Host "  Read data from test.txt: $(Get-Content (Join-Path $Dir 'test.txt') -ErrorAction Continue)";
      }

And get the following output:
$ # all the paths used for RSA key storage must exist - apparently that's not the case on the hosted runners # collapsed multi-line command
Directory for key storage already exists: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys
  Can access directory for key storage (Test-Path)? True
  Read data from test.txt: Test
Creating directory for key storage: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-18
    Directory: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                 
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                 
d-----         5/23/2024   1:47 PM                S-1-5-18                                                             
  Can access directory for key storage (Test-Path)? True
  Read data from test.txt: Test
Creating directory for key storage: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-19
d-----         5/23/2024   1:47 PM                S-1-5-19                                                             
  Can access directory for key storage (Test-Path)? True
  Read data from test.txt: Test
Creating directory for key storage: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-20
d-----         5/23/2024   1:47 PM                S-1-5-20                                                             
  Can access directory for key storage (Test-Path)? True
  Read data from test.txt: Test
Creating directory for key storage: C:\Users\gitlab_runner\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\S-1-5-21-871912310-883878684-2729644526-1001
    Directory: C:\Users\gitlab_runner\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                 
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                 
d-----         5/23/2024   1:47 PM                S-1-5-21-871912310-883878684-2729644526-1001                         
  Can access directory for key storage (Test-Path)? True
  Read data from test.txt: Test
Creating directory for key storage: C:\Users\gitlab_runner\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto\Keys
    Directory: C:\Users\gitlab_runner\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Crypto
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                 
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                 
d-----         5/23/2024   1:47 PM                Keys                                                                 
  Can access directory for key storage (Test-Path)? True
  Read data from test.txt: Test
Creating directory for key storage: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\SystemKeys
    Directory: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                 
----                 -------------         ------ ----                                                                 
d-----         5/23/2024   1:47 PM                SystemKeys                                                           
  Can access directory for key storage (Test-Path)? True
  Read data from test.txt: Test

